# PHP preg_match simple mathematical expression using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to make sure the input is valid for simple calculation. Hence, I want to get character matching only these

> 0 to 9, + - * / ( )

So I have `~[^0-9()+\-*/]~` as my regex. [It works fine here](http://regexr.com/4hktv)

So I have this code in PHP.

```
$exp = (1+2*3)+4;
if(preg_match('~[^0-9()+\-*/]~', $exp)){
  eval("echo $exp;");
} else {
  echo "Bad Expression!";
}
```

And this gives me "Bad Expression!"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use: `~^[0-9()+*/-]+$~`

Comment: You forgot to escape the \.

Comment: @Leonard: Your pattern is the good one, it isn't the problem: all you have to do is to exchange the code for success with the code for failure. (or to negate the `preg_match` function in your `if` condition). https://3v4l.org/L0SgV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/BlPMuR/1). You also need to escape the divide (/) symbol.

```
$exp = (1+2*3)+4;
if(preg_match('~^[0-9()+\-*\/]+$~', $exp)){
  eval("echo $exp;");
} else {
   echo "Bad Expression!";
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://3v4l.org/c4v5i)

Comment: @Leonard Demo is added.

Comment: Thanks! this works now. But how does ^ work here?
If it is inside the set it negates the pattern. But when it is outside, it says "Matches beginning of the string". 

But this explanation does not make any sense to me.

Comment: `^` is the start position of a string. https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: Ah I get it now! I was accidentally looking at JavaScript regex checker thats why it showed me an error. 
Yeah it makes sense now. It is just checking to see if there is one more matches of that pattern or not. THanks!

Comment: *"You also need to escape the divide (/) symbol."*: No, the slash isn't a regex special character. It's only needed when you use it as pattern delimiter. This isn't the case here. Also take care that the `$` anchor can also match before a trailing newline (you can prevent this behaviour adding the D modifier or using `\z` in place of `$`).

Comment: Note that his regex was already the good one (and the best IMO). The pattern wasn't the problem: https://3v4l.org/L0SgV